# Подсветить ссылки меню в зависимости от скролла страницы (по заголовкам в тексте)

Tags: javascript

Есть код JavaScrpt, который отвечает за боковое меню страницы. Он считывает все `h2`,`h3` теги на странице и копирует их в `div class="articles_tags_list_content"`, оборачивает в тег `a`, и делает плавный скролл по клику от тега `a` к соответствующему заголовку. Подскажите как добавлять `class="active"` к ссылкам в меню (при скролле страницы), в зависимости от того какая часть текста сейчас отображается на экране. Я нашла пример на jQuery, но хочу добиться результата на чистом JavaScrpt. Вот пример того, как должно работать:

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  var $sections = $('section');
  $sections.each(function(i, el) {
    var top = $(el).offset().top - 100;
    var bottom = top + $(el).height();
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var id = $(el).attr('id');
    if (scroll > top && scroll < bottom) {
      $('a.active').removeClass('active');
      $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');

    }
  })
});

$("nav").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  // исключаем стандартную реакцию браузера
  event.preventDefault();

  // получем идентификатор блока из атрибута href
  var id = $(this).attr('href'),

    // находим высоту, на которой расположен блок
    top = $(id).offset().top;

  // анимируем переход к блоку, время: 800 мс
  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: top
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
section {
  font: bold 24px/700px Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ededed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

section#block1 {
  background: #F05222;
}

section#block2 {
  background: #7CBA01;
}

section#block3 {
  background: #00A6F0;
}

section#block4 {
  background: #FFB901;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ededed;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a.active {
  color: #f95;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#block1"> Block 1 </a>
  <a href="#block2"> Block 2 </a>
  <a href="#block3" class=""> Block3 </a>
  <a href="#block4"> Block 4 </a>
</nav>
<div>
  <section id="block1" class="nav">block 1</section>
  <section id="block2" class="nav">block 2</section>
  <section id="block3" class="nav">block 3</section>
  <section id="block4" class="nav">block 4</section>
  <div>
```

Вот мой код JavaScrpt, в котором я хочу добиться нужного результата:

```js
let tags = document.querySelectorAll('h2,h3')
let nav = document.querySelector('.articles_tags_list_content')

for (let tag of tags) {
  let a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = '#'
  a.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML
  nav.append(a)
  a.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    tag.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
  })
}
```

```css
.articles_tags_list_content {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 35px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: max-content;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.articles_tags_list_content a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="articles_tags_list_content">
</div>

<div>

  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The
  access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department. hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer
  service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department.

  <h2>Заголовок 1</h2>

  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The
  access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department. hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer
  service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department.

  <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>

  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The
  access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department. hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer
  service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department.

  <h2>Заголовок 3</h2>

  No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the
  hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get reports about the customer’s feedback. The
  access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department. No business can thrive without providing exceptional customer services to its clientele. It is why many turn towards the customer service supervisor dashboard to get
  reports about the customer’s feedback. The access to this dashboard is usually in the hands of the head of the CS department.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот как-то так (только не забудьте класс active добавить в CSS):

```
        let tags = document.querySelectorAll('h2,h3')
        let nav = document.querySelector('.articles_tags_list_content');       

        for (let tag of tags) {
            let a = document.createElement('a')
            a.href = '#'
            a.innerHTML = tag.innerHTML
            nav.append(a)
            a.addEventListener('click', e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                tag.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'smooth'
                })
            })
        } 

        window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);

        function onScroll(){
            let refs = nav.querySelectorAll('a');
            const  windowPosition = { //координаты окна
                top: window.pageYOffset,
                bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight
            };

            const tagPosition = []; // координаты заголовков

            for (let tag of tags) {
                tagPosition.push({
                    top: window.pageYOffset + tag.getBoundingClientRect().top,
                    bottom: window.pageYOffset + tag.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
                });
            }
            for (let i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
                if (tagPosition[i].top < windowPosition.bottom && 
                (i<tags.length-1 ? tagPosition[i+1].top > windowPosition.top + 20 : true)){
                    // 20 - просто для примера, значение надо менять в зависимости от величины шрифта
                    refs[i].classList.add('active');
                } else{
                    refs[i].classList.remove('active');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно сделать так, что бы класс оставался пока в область экрана не попадет следующий заголовок? Типа подсвечивался читаемый раздел. Сейчас если между заголовками много текста то не горит ни одна ссылка.

Comment: Для этого нужно соответствующим образом неравенство настроить.

Comment: Это как? ) Не совсем понимаю

Comment: Можно отслеживать, докрутили ли следующий заголовок до верхней границы окна. Если еще не докрутили, ссылка на предыдущий абзац остается активной. Я исправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли